# Is Mongolia a good place to host a no-moderation social media website?

Tags: freedom-of-speech

Between Mongolia and Canada, can you tell which country is less censored in terms of online freedom of speech?

Answer (score 5):

Mongolia apparently has a [list of banned words](http://www.shuum.mn/news/newsid/14091/catid/17) (list is NSFW) that websites can't use.  And according to [this State Department report](https://www.state.gov/j/drl/rls/hrrpt/2012humanrightsreport/index.htm?year=2012&dlid=204222#wrapper):

> Additionally, the regulation requires Web sites with heavy traffic to use filtering software that makes the user Internet Protocol addresses of those commenting or sharing content publicly visible.

The report also says:

> The law places the burden of proof on the defendant in libel and slander cases, and both defamation and insult are criminal charges. NGOs reported that these laws were used more frequently than in previous years to control the press.

Canada is probably a better choice, even if it isn't perfect.

Comment: @user6726 huh. They also banned "huh." (#574). I had no idea that was a bad word before today.

Comment: Lulz. That could be the transliteration of Mongolian хух ?"animal". Also banned is хүнд суртал and the transliteration hund surtal: "bureaucracy". See 575-579 for a range of variants. "meem" is apparently on the list as a transliteration of мөөм "breast", not a bad spelling of "meme".